# PyQt: QImage() returns a 'Null'-Image

Tags: python, qt, web-scraping, pyqt, pyqt4

I need to take screenshots of websites for a project of mine. As development language I use Python and to take the Screenshots I use Webkit from PyQt. The script below is the code used to take capture the websites (it's partially modified but most of it is still equal to the original from [webscraping.com](https://webscraping.com/blog/Webpage-screenshots-with-webkit/)).

Now my problem is the following:
Most of the time it works without any problems, but, from time to time it happens that the following exception.

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QPainter::pen: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

I've already tracked down the problem to the creation of the image

```
image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
```

The QImage returned by this line is sometime Null - I checked this using the .isNull()-method of QImage.
According to the Qt documentation this happens if there isn't enough memory to allocate a new QImage, but I still have way enough free memory.
This beahaviour occured while running on windows and also on linux, so it should not depend on some os depending stuff, I think. I'm new to Qt and PyQt, so I hope someone can help me.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys
import time

# ############################################################# #
# This script is based on the following script:                 #
# https://webscraping.com/blog/Webpage-screenshots-with-webkit/ #
# ############################################################# #

class Screenshot(QWebView):
    _instance = None

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance():
        # TODO: Add a lock around the if including the creation!
        if Screenshot._instance is None:
            Screenshot._instance = Screenshot()

        return Screenshot._instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self._loaded = False
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)

    def capture(self, url, output_file):
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.wait_load()
        # set to webpage size
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        self.page().setViewportSize(frame.contentsSize())
        # render image
        # creating the image. Here it happens that QImage returns a 'Null'-Image
        image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        # check if there's no image allocated
        if image.isNull(): 
            print 'image.isNull() is True'
        if image is None:
            print 'image is None is True'
        painter = QPainter(image)
        frame.render(painter)
        painter.end()
        print 'saving', output_file
        image.save(output_file)

    def wait_load(self, delay=0):
        # process app events until page loaded
        while not self._loaded:
            self.app.processEvents()
            time.sleep(delay)
        self._loaded = False

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self._loaded = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # a simple way to get the exceptions is to try to create multiple screenshots
    sc = Screenshot()
    for i in range(0, 25):
        sc.capture('http://google.de', str(i) + '.png')

    for i in range(25, 50):
        sc.capture('http://de.wikipedia.org', str(i) + '.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've tracked the problem a bit further down. It seems like the contentsSize of the QWebPages mainFrame is sometimes (0, 0) when it is read to create the QImage.

```
frame = self.page().mainFrame()
self.page().setViewportSize(frame.contentsSize()) # frame.contentsSize() = (0, 0)
image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32) # so we're creating here an Image with Width: 0 and Height: 0
```

So basically the QImage seems to be Null, because the size it's created with is (0, 0).
This problem can be solved by checking wether the mainFrames contentsSize is (0, 0) or not. If it is (0, 0) it's needed to process outstanding events on the QApplication until the new contentsSize is set. I'm doing this now with the following piece of code:

```
if frame.contentsSize().width() == 0 or frame.contentsSize().height() == 0:
    print 'ContentsSize = (w: {}, h: {})'.format(frame.contentsSize().width(), frame.contentsSize().height())
    count = 0 # used so we're not starting an infinite loop
    while (frame.contentsSize().width() == 0 or frame.contentsSize().height() == 0) and count < 5:
        count += 1
        self.app.processEvents()
        time.sleep(1)
```